# UTF-8 characters are not printed correctly on the console

Tags: terminal, unicode

I've seen some questions similar to this one but I'm not being able to use the solutions of those to help me.
So, what is my problem?, I have a file with the characters `ç`, `ã`, `à`, etc... but they don't print on the terminal when I use either `awk`, `cat`, `grep`, etc... The terminal and my font can and do support these characters.

My locale is set to `en_GB.UTF-8` and the output of the command `locale` is:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Comment: 1. Can you paste ç, ã, à in your terminal and see them? 2. Can you `echo "ç, ã, à" > testfile; cat testfile` and see how it works?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov What you said works just fine!!! When I do ```file testfile````, It says its UTF-8

Comment: The way the question is formulated is wrong. The solution is also wrong.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, thanks for the input, very constructive m8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! I simply had to convert the files to `UTF-8`, they where in `ISO-8859`.

To see the file's current encoding: `file <path-to-file>`
Then, to convert said file to UTF-8: `iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 >> <path-to-converted-file>`

This should fix the 'problem';